# Using LWJGL version 2.8.4, added lwjgl_util to project cant find import?

Tags: eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I have been racking my brain all morning with this. I am using Eclipse and trying to import this 'org.lwjgl.opengl.glu.Sphere;' to my class. but Eclipse can't find this class.
I have been informed in my research that this class resides in lwjgl_util.jar which I have included in the java build path for this project in eclipse. everything else imports except the .glu classes. what am I missing?

Comment: If you can paste here some code then may be we can help you :) Have you connected the LWJGL JARS and dlls correctly ?

Comment: I have discovered from further research that these are deprecated. I was trying to follow some NeHe tutorials which are apparently out dated. The paths for these classes have been changed and some like org.lwjgl.devil.* are no longer used.

Comment: why is it so hard to find progressive tutorials for lwjgll? Somebody should have written a book by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , to setup Eclipse with LWJGL go to LWJGL Wiki [page](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse) and there you can find nice and detailed tutorial.For the OpenGL modern pipeline tutorials.One nice guy ported examples from "OpenGL SuperBible 5" to LWJGL.[Here](https://code.google.com/r/zaphosmatthewnicholls-opengl-superbible-java/) you will find them.The tutorials use OpenGL 3.3 which means all the old (fixed) functionality ,that you have probably seen in tutorials of NEHE ,is ignored.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this for my project using lwjgl 2.8.5
the classpath is `org.lwjgl.util.glu.Sphere` it is located in `lwjgl_util-2.8.5.jar` maven dependency is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.lwjgl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl_util</artifactId>
        <version>${org.lwjgl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```